# React Hooks: using state in useEffect without depending on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have run into a situation in React where I want to run a function `F` in a useEffect hook whenever a value `V1` from the store changes. `F` uses another value from the store `V2`. I only want to run `F` when `V1` changes, but to have access to the latest value of `V2`. This means I wouldn't want to include `V2` in the list of dependencies for the useEffect.

Below is my current solution, but I wonder if there is a more accepted way of achieving this.

```js
const v1 = useSelector(state => state.v1);
const v2 = useSelector(state => state.v2);

const v2_ref = useRef(v2);
useEffect(() => {v2_ref.current = v2}, [v2]);

useEffect(() => {
  v1 ? doSomething(v2_ref.current) : doSomethingElse();
}, [v1]);
```

Comment: I think that if you want to `have access to the latest value of X` you need to use the `useRef` hook. I don't see other way of doing it

Comment: I figured, but I thought maybe there was a different pattern/style for achieving this. I ended up creating a useDynamicRef hook for this functionality.